# angular directive parameters

Tags: angularjs, parameters, directive

I want to have a directive with a parameter so that I can render it as follows:

```
<ng-polite-captcha name="@Const.NoCaptchaResponseField"
                   challenge=" @Const.NoCaptchaChallengeField"></ng-polite-captcha>
```

Here's my directive definition:

```
app.directive('ngPoliteCaptcha', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            challenge: '@'
        },
        template: '<input type="hidden" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value }}" />',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            var response = angular.element('[name="' + $scope.challenge + '"]');
            if (response && response.val())
                $scope.value = response.val().split('').reverse().join('');
        }]
    };
});
```

The rendered input looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="nocaptcha_response " challenge="nocaptcha_challenge">
```

How do I make angular to stop rendering the "challenge" attribute on the input? it's not in the template.. it's transfered from the markup in chich I call the directive

Comment: really not sure why removing it matters to you. You are binding that attribute to scope... so removing it could cause unexpected behavior. Could try `element.removeAttr()` in `link` of directive

Comment: I want to remove it for the sake of being semantic. I found a description in the docs that this is expected behavior, so I just changed the attribute name to data-challenge